# Can't build c++ project in CLion

Tags: c++, clion

I have a hello-wrold project:
**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "square.h"
    int main() {
        int z = 5;
        std::cout << square(z) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

**square.cpp:**

```
int square(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

**square.h:**

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

int square(int x);

#endif //SQUARE_H
```

It compiles and runs with g++ from terminal:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c square.cpp
g++ main.o square.o -o programm
./programm
>25
```

But the CLion's build end up with:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cpp_code
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "square(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [cpp_code] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_code.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_code.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [cpp_code] Error 2
```

**P.S.** I used to write simple c++ programms for a long time(with big pauses though), and this is the first time, im facing problems at this step. Also, there's a `CMakeList.txt` automaticly created(in VisStud there was nothing similar!)
**CMakeList.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(cpp_code)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(cpp_code main.cpp)
```

Comment: You need to build with `square.cpp` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_executable` expects the list of files that need to be compiled to create said executable. Add `square.cpp` to that list.

```
add_executable(cpp_code main.cpp square.cpp)
```

Comment: Ha, that's it... 
Why do i have to do it? 
In visual studio everything was fine even without it

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Visual Studio uses .vcxproj files (MSBuild) which also list source files. You use the "Include in project" menu option to automatically add a new file. CLion defers as much as possible to CMake. IIRC it shoud be able to add the file automatically, but I don't remember where that is in the GUI.

Comment: Did you use the same `CMakeLists.txt` with Visual Studio? If you did I would expect the same error.